# R: Generating Model for User Preference Structure to be used in Random Pairwise Comparisons

Tags: r, comparison, matching, montecarlo

On a generated set of men and women, I want to have them rate each other in a random set of pairwise comparisons.

Example:

```
Match1: Man1 compares Woman1 vs. Woman2. W2 > W1
Match2: Man1 compares Woman2 vs. Woman3. W3 > W2
...
Preferences of Man1 pM1: W3 > W2 > W1
```

I recreated generic sets with information from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.04783.pdf) and [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232905806_Asymmetries_of_Men_and_Women_in_Selecting_Partner). Each men, woman has certain characteristics (gender, height, age, education, income, bmi) and preferences for an ideal partner. Example:

```
   playerID gender height age education income  bmi prefHeight prefAge prefEducation prefIncome
1        7      0    167  22         2      4 19.5     173.24   23.52          2.84       6.05
2        8      0    161  21         4      2 21.1     170.95   27.93          3.84       6.33
3        9      0    168  34         5      5 19.8     184.05   40.08          6.45       6.41
4       10      0    171  28         4      4 18.7     169.39   24.16          2.53       3.91
...
```

Now, I want now to generate a random set of say 100 pairwise comparisons by each player. So if in my network there are 60 men and 40 women, 100 players would each compare 100x two random profiles -> 10.000 comparisons.

How do I calculate the probability that player 1 with his preferences prefers player 7 over player 8?